# Python strftime is giving me Italian

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

This is a really weird thing happening in my django models.

In my save function I take a DatetimeField and populate another field with a string based on that date like this:

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(self.date, "%A %d %b")
```

Now the weird thing is it outs it out in Italian for some crazy reason!

```
Martedì 07 Gen
```

Well I believe its Italian?

This only happens in  the model save method, not anywhere else Im using strftime.

Comment: What's your locale set to?

Comment: If both fields contain the same value then why do this in the first place?

Comment: Its for an external program that cannot read the datetime fields. Thats besides the point, isn't it?

Comment: django settings LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

Comment: rmnunn I set it in python now: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "en_US"). Now its fine. I dont know how this changed!